# Анимация в TabHost

Tags: android, tab, android-material, android-tabs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поставлена задача: При нажатии на элемент из списка табов он окрашивается в полу-прозрачный белый с анимацией. Вопрос: как убрать такую анимацию?